# Fill In A Null Column When Data Is Submitted On Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

so I am having an issue with a shopping cart. I am trying to transfer the Title and Price columns out of a cart table (tblCart) and send them into a purchased items table (tblPurchaseItem). This works fine like it is suppose to. Now the problem is that the tblPurchaseItem has an extra column called PurchaseID that is not in the tblCart. Now on a button "Checkout" click this takes place. My issue I am having is that I am trying to set a value to the new rows added into tblPurchaseItem each time the table from cart is transferred over. So say tblCart is added with a list of movies I would like all of them to have the same value in the tblPurchaseItem. The next time somebody clicks the "Checkout" button I would like that new table from tblCart to be sent to tblPurchaseItem to be the value of the last one +1. When I try this my PurchaseID column is staying = to null and is taking no values. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code for the "Checkout" button:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        purID += 1;
        cn.Open();
        String cmdString = "INSERT INTO tblPurchaseItem(Title, Price) Select Title, Price from tblCart";
        String cmdString3 = "DELETE from tblCart";
        String cmdString4 = "Select * from tblPurchaseItem";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(cmdString3, cn);
        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(cmdString4, cn);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
        dt = new DataTable("tblPurchaseItem");
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                String cmdString2 = "UPDATE tblPurchaseItem set PurchaseID = '" + purID + "' where PurchaseID is Null";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString2, cn);
            }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So all in all, say the first table sent to the tblPurchaseItem when the user clicks "Checkout" would be assigned the purID of 1. The next time the Checkout button is clicked I would like those values to be assigned to 2, and so on. So each transaction would have a its own purID.

Comment: after this line SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString2, cn); add cmd2.ExecutenonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code quite a lot:

```
    cn.Open();

    String cmdString = "INSERT INTO tblPurchaseItem(Title, Price, PurchaseID) Select Title, Price, @PurchaseID from tblCart";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchaseID", purID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    String cmdString3 = "DELETE from tblCart";
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(cmdString3, cn);
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My reasoning is that your queries were far too vague, e.g. they affected whole tables indiscriminately. I'm still concerned that you transfer the whole tblCart table and clear it all out. If your system has multiple users, I imagine you would want a UserID column in the cart and only affect rows for that one user.

Comment: great answer the parameters thing is helping great.  Just getting into sql querys and c#, the answer was marked and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to normalise your database more. For example have a tblPurchase table which represents a single transaction, where tblPurchaseItem contains all the items belonging to the one purchase. Then your tblPurchase table can have an identity int column which provides the purchaseID values for your tblPurchaseItem table. You can do something like the below when inserting:

```
insert into tblPurchase(customerID, orderDate)
values (@customerID, getdate());

select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

You can run that using ExecuteScalar, then use the int ID returned when inserting rows into tblPurchaseItem.

Comment: How it is set up is that tblCart, I think would be what you say tblPurchase would be.  So as the user adds a movie to the listview, that would be a check out box, each movie gets stored into the tblCart.

Comment: Once the user is ready to purchase the items on the list, that list is transferred to tblPurchaseItem.  The tblPurchaseItem has 4 columns: the ID(that is incremented), the Purchase ID (that is null that I am trying to fill in with a value that is different for each table received from tblCart), Title, and Price.  Everything is right going to the table.  My question is to figure out how to assign each table (from tblCart) sent to tblPurchaseItem a value for the purID (which is stuck being null ;)).

Comment: I think we're disagreeing on the best practice here. I believe you need another table, I've tried generating unique integer IDs myself and you have to be so careful to avoid duplicates. If you get a duplicate then you end up with different purchases being mixed together and it will be awful to fix. However, that said I will do another post just addressing the code bugs. :)